# i cannot connect firebase to my html file

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm

i am doing net ninjas JS course and in that there's a chapter for databases that uses firebase. but his code for firebase is fairly different from now and I'm struggling with npm and node.js. I followed the documentation from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".
but when I add type="module" to app.js I get a different error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."
below is my code:-

HTML :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:-

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaS.....bFkMOXoRY",
  authDomain: "modern.....irebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "mode....nja",
  storageBucket: "modern-j......ja.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "9635.....932978",
  appId: "1:96350793.......cbf567939ae91512b",
  measurementId: "G-HFN5111EHZ"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

everything is copy-pasted from the app that I created. please help

Comment: please see this solution [You should replace references in other files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71497816/10765272)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change your imports to this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js";
```

You can find more info about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdk-and-initialize).

You are using browser modules so you need to use those imports. This is what stands in the docu about it:

[image]

Comment: i just added this and it worked. can I ask from where do you get the link to the properties? (like if I wanted to get for authentication what would the link be etc) and could you explain why just typing 'firebase/firestore' results in  "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." even tho type = module is written in the file that contains these import things?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. I hope that helps. Let me know if you need more info.