# Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

I was working on a chrome browser extension. When I tried to connect firebase with the web app in 2 possible ways none is working.

1. using "npm install firebase"
   When I tried this command to install firebase into my project folder and written a fireConn.js file along with the configuration I got from firebase project created online.

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
```

The error which I got is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

2. using the https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js url to get connected with the firebase

```
import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js";
import {getFirestore} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-firestore.js";
```

As my project is a chrome extension, I have a manifest.json file which is in the following format:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["cookies","tabs"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'https://apis.google.com/' 'https://www.gstatic.com/' 'https://*.firebaseio.com' 'https://www.googleapis.com' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

The error which I was getting is:(something went wrong with the content_security_policy)

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-firestore.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Could you please try installing with this command "npm install firebase@9.4.1 --save" once? Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi Mousumi Roy, I have tried that command but still it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the imports as below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-firestore.js";
```

You can find more information regarding it from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdk-and-initialize).
Since you are using a module bundler,  needs type="module" to be added to it. The correct format should be:

```
<script type="module" src="........”></script>
```

Please note: src depends on how you set the path.

You may also refer to the video [Getting started with Firebase for the web – Firebase Fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ&t=343s).
Also, the [Cannot connect to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197047/i-cannot-connect-firebase-to-my-html-file),[Uncaught Error in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644782/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-firebase-app-relative) might add to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace https://www.gstatic.com/ references in other files

in firebase-firestore.js

```
import { _registerComponent, registerVersion, _getProvider, getApp, _removeServiceInstance, SDK_VERSION } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js';
```

change to  line

```
import { _registerComponent, registerVersion, _getProvider, getApp, _removeServiceInstance, SDK_VERSION } from './firebase-app.js';
```